# Is there a calculation to estimate OpenCV HAAR training time?

Tags: c++, opencv, estimation, haar-classifier

Does anyone have a calculation or way to estimate the time it will take a computer to train a HAAR cascade file using OpenCV 2.4.10? And if there isn't a calculation what would be a good approach to making a timing estimate?

I'm getting more into Computer Vision and have been reading a lot of blogs and the OpenCV website, but the overwhelming response is that it will just take "a while" and not anything that more detailed timing or working out how to estimate the time it will take to train.

I do understand that the variables are wide, and that CPU, Operating System, RAM, number of samples (positive and negative), as well as the version of OpenCV all matter. But I'd like to try to understand how long it will take and not just fluctuate between 8 hours and a week as my estimates.

Comment: for haar training, between 8 hours and a week makes sense. it's a bit of a shame, that you're using outdated opencv2.1, more recent versions allow you to try a lbp or hog cascade first (slighly less accurate, but tons faster)

Comment: I put in the wrong version of OpenCV, thanks for calling attention to that. I'm on the latest prior to the 3.x Alpha that is out now.

Comment: ah, ok. so again: try an lbp cascade first. if that does not work at all, your haar cascade never will.

Comment: Thanks, but my question isn't about getting OpenCV running it's about working out a way to know how long it will take to train. I haven't run the other kinds of trainers yet but do they give you a time estimate for how long they will take to train? If not do you have any sense of how to figure that out? Or can possibly point me to somewhere that is demonstrated? Searching online and in StackOverflow gives me zero relevant results to that question.

Comment: no, there's no exact formula. time requirements go exponential with window size / num_images / num_stages though, that's why you want to 'prototype' with the most cheap/fast one.

Comment: Right, and it is that base timing that I'm looking to understand or at least get a baseline to begin working out a formula to do an estimation script. It would be based on the environment and values that will be passed to the trainer. I've started reading the code for the trainer and hopefully that will help get me started, but if anyone has some insight into this that they are willing to share that would be appreciated.

Comment: I should perform the training phase on a virtual machine, trying to complete process in several hours. considering how expensive cloud computing can be, could you suggest the main requirements of the machine I need to rent?
I've been suggested Azure: is it a good solution? which are the features of RAM, disk space and processor's speed I should require?